# Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll not found exception only in Class Library output type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Attempting to use `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient 15.112.1`
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

Using Visual Studio 2017

This code in a console app works just fine:

```
string tfsUrl = "{{tfsurl}}";
string project = "{{project}}";
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(tfsUrl));
ITestManagementService tms = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
var proj = tms.GetTeamProject(project);
```

This code in a TestMethod as part of a Unit Test project does not:

```
string tfsUrl = "{{tfsurl}}";
string project = "{{project}}";
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(tfsUrl));
ITestManagementService tms = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
var proj = tms.GetTeamProject(project);
Assert.IsNotNull(proj);
```

It throws an exception on the `tms.GetTeamProject(project)`: 
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

Solutions I have tried:

- Copying the WITDataStore32.dll to the bin directory
- Copying WITDataStore32.dll from the `packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient.15.112.1\lib\native\x86` folder and into the `C:\Windows\System32`
- Copying WITDataStore32.dll from the `packages\Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient.15.112.1\lib\native\x86` folder and into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE` folder
- Installing the Team Foundation Server TFS Package and copying the WITDataStore32.dll from the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer` folder and into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE` folder

Nothing has worked so far...

Full stack dump below:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DataStoreNative32.CreateDatastore(IntPtr& handle)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DataStoreNative.CreateDatastore(IntPtr& handle)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ITfsTeamProjectCollectionObject.Initialize(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.InitializeTeamFoundationObject(String fullName, Object instance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.CreateServiceInstance(Assembly assembly, String fullName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.GetWitProject()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.get_WitHelper()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.get_SharedParameterDataSetWorkItemTypeName()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.get_HasSupportForSharedParameterDataSets()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject..ctor(TestManagementService manager, String projectName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementService.<GetTeamProject>b__0_0(String name)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ObjectCache`2.Get(Key key, Creator creator)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementService.GetTeamProject(String projectName)
   at CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1() in c:\users\me\source\repos\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITest1.cs:line 32
Result Message: 
Test method CodedUITestProject1.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client

Then when creating an installer, then you need to take the file above from the output directory, add it as a resource (copy always) to your file. The Publish activity will otherwise not recognize it, and thus the execution will fail.

Comment: Yes what works for now is to configure it in the project build settings to manually copy the file from the local nuget package and into the output directory. That way we don't need to check the .dll into source control and it can still run on our self-container build servers.